# NHibernate Many To Many

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between

Portfolio and PortfolioTags

A portfolio Item can have many PortfolioTags

I am looking at the best way of saving tags to a portfolio item. My Nhibnerate maps are like so:

```
 public class PortfolioMap : ClassMap<Portfolio> {

        public PortfolioMap() {
            Table("Portfolio");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
            Map(x => x.AliasTitle).Column("AliasTitle").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.MetaDescription).Column("MetaDescription").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Title).Column("Title").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Client).Column("Client").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Summary).Column("Summary").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Url).Column("Url");
            Map(x => x.MainImage).Column("MainImage");
            Map(x => x.TitleAlt).Column("TitleAlt");
            Map(x => x.Description).Column("Description").Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.PortfolioImage).KeyColumn("PortfolioId").Inverse();
            HasMany(x => x.PortfolioTag).KeyColumn("PortfolioId").Cascade.All().Table("PortfolioTag").Inverse();
        }
    }

public class PortfoliotagMap : ClassMap<Portfoliotag> {

    public PortfoliotagMap() {
        Table("PortfolioTag");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        References(x => x.Portfolio).Column("PortfolioId");
        References(x => x.Tag).Column("TagId");
    }
}



 public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag>
{

      public TagMap() {
        Table("Tag");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.TagId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("TagId");
        Map(x => x.TagVal).Column("Tag").Not.Nullable();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Portfolio).Table("PortfolioTag").ParentKeyColumn("TagId").ChildKeyColumn("PortfolioId").Inverse();
    }
    }
```

In my portfolio controller I am first trying to save my tags that do not exist. I tried using SaveOrUpdate on a tag repository. However as the ids are different multiple save of tags occurs at this point.

I thought about the following steps but it seems long winded:

1) getting all tags:
      var tags = _tagRepository.GetAll();

2) Iterating over the tags from the item to save and seeing if they exist in the database. If so I would need to get the tag and associate with the portfolio item. If not i would need to save the tag one by one and then associate with the portfolio item.

```
        var tags = _tagRepository.GetAll();

        foreach (var tagInPortfolio in StringUtilities.SplitToList(model.Tags, new[] { ',' }))
        {
            // tag does not exist so save it
            if (tags.Any(i => i.TagVal == tagInPortfolio))
            {
                _tagRepository.SaveOrUpdate(new Tag {TagVal = tagInPortfolio});
            }
        }
```

3) I then need to delete any relationships i.e. tags to portfolio items that dont exist.

4) Finally need to add the tag to to the portfolioTag. I would need to get all the tags again and then associate:

```
  portfolio.PortfolioTag.Add(new Portfoliotag {Portfolio = portfolio, Tag = tag});

 _portfolioRepository.UpdateCommit(portfolio);
```

This seems to long winded. Can anyone explain the most simplest way of doing this please.

I have looked at saveandcommit on tags but i get multiple inserts because of ids being different. Do I need to delete all existing tag relationships also as this seems to much logic for something simple.

Create now works with a commit -

```
public void CreateCommit(T entity)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.Save(entity); 
            transaction.Commit();
        }

    }
```

However using the below and the above maps still meant duplicates where occurring in the tag table. So if one portfolio record added a tag like abc and another portfolio record added a tag abc i need the join table to reference the same record in the tag and not create another instance of abc. Do i need to do a lookup on the tag table to avoid this

```
public void UpdateCommit(T entity)
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Session.Update(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: *I would suggest (as I do) to think about this approach: 1) Let user on UI create new tags ... and persist them in one operation. 2) Portfolio should then just work with existing tags. Second operation will then always work with Portfolio object which has set of pairs referencing the existing Tags. In case you cannot do that on UI, do that on a server (Create view model and apply above operations iterating that)...*

Comment: i have tried this also but no joy - http://www.aaronstannard.com/fluent-nhibernate-bidirectional-many-to-many/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think you misunderstood the many-to-many mapping. If you really have a relationship like this between the Portifolio and the Tag classes, you should **not** map the PortfolioTag table.

In a simple many-to-many relationship the table used to connect the other two main tables should have only the foreign keys from the two tables (that would also be a composite key of this intermediate table). In this case, the PortfolioTag table would have only two columns: **PortfolioId** and **TagId**, that would be not only foreign keys for the Portfolio and Tag tables, but also the primary key of this intermediate table.

In this case, your Portfolio class should have a list of **Tags** instead of a list of *PortfolioTag*, and the Tag class a list of **Portfolios**. And you should map the Portfolio and the Tag like this (with no need of mapping the intermediate table):

```
public class PortfolioMap : ClassMap<Portfolio> {
    public PortfolioMap() {
        Table("Portfolio");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        //
        // Code intentionally omitted for clarity
        //
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags)
         .Table("PortfolioTag")
         .ParentKeyColumn("PortfolioId")
         .ChildKeyColumn("TagId")
         .LazyLoad()
         .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}

public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag> {
    public TagMap() {
        Table("Tag");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.TagVal).Column("Tag").Not.Nullable();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Portfolios)
         .Table("PortfolioTag")
         .ParentKeyColumn("TagId")
         .ChildKeyColumn("PortfolioId")
         .Inverse();
    }
}
```

You will also have to save the Portfolio inside the context of a transaction for the intermediate table to be populated, like bellow:

```
using (var trans = Session.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
        trans.Commit();
    } catch {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}

//or like this (with TransactionScope)

using (var trans = new TransactionScope()) {
    Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
    trans.Complete();
}
```

With this approach, you would also be excused of the need to iterate through the Tags list to save each one. You would be able to just save the Portfolio and everything should be fine.

P.S.: I tested this code with **FluentNHibernate v1.4.0.0** and **NHibernate v3.3.1.4000**.

Comment: hi i added this amend. The one thing that is still happening is the middle joining table is not adding records on insert. It works on updates. Also on updates the right table, i.e. the tags are duplicated again rather than refering to the existing record

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot to mention that you need to save the Portfolio inside a transaction for this to work. I will edit my answer to show this.

Comment: I am still getting duplicated on save and update. Create works with commit but i still get duplicates. Do i need a constraint on a duplicate or no id on the tag table. I dont think nhibernate works with no id.

Comment: What exactly is getting duplicated? Have you removed the loop that were saving each tag?