# Many to Many Nhibernate - Duplicate records and no insert

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have three tables in a many to many relationship with the nhibernate maps below. My objects are also below. A portfolio item can have many tags. The problem I am having is

1) update save another tag even when the name is the same as last time. So duplicate records get inserted into tag when the tag is the same. So for example if the tag for one portfolio object was abc the next portfolio item that adds the tag should reference this record rather than reinserting abc. I think this is because of the id column in the tag map. Nhibernate needs an id though.

2) Create does not add records in the join table. Records in the join table are only added on updates.

Domain Objects

```
public class Portfolio {
    public Portfolio() {
        PortfolioImage = new List<Portfolioimage>();
        Tag = new List<Tag>();
    }
    public virtual int PortfolioId { get; set; }
    public virtual string AliasTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Client { get; set; }
    public virtual string Summary { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string MainImage { get; set; }
    public virtual string TitleAlt { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Portfolioimage> PortfolioImage { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Portfoliotag {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag {
    public Tag() {
        Portfolio = new List<Portfolio>();
    }
    public virtual int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual string TagVal { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Portfolio> Portfolio { get; set; }
}
```

Maps

```
     public class PortfolioMap : ClassMap<Portfolio> {

        public PortfolioMap() {
            Table("Portfolio");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.PortfolioId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("PortfolioId");
            Map(x => x.AliasTitle).Column("AliasTitle").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.MetaDescription).Column("MetaDescription").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Title).Column("Title").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Client).Column("Client").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Summary).Column("Summary").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Url).Column("Url");
            Map(x => x.MainImage).Column("MainImage");
            Map(x => x.TitleAlt).Column("TitleAlt");
            Map(x => x.Description).Column("Description").Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.PortfolioImage).KeyColumn("PortfolioId").Inverse();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Tag).Table("PortfolioTag").ParentKeyColumn("PortfolioId").ChildKeyColumn("TagId").LazyLoad().Cascade.All().Fetch.Join();
        }
    }

        public class PortfoliotagMap : ClassMap<Portfoliotag> {

        public PortfoliotagMap() {
            Table("PortfolioTag");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
            References(x => x.Portfolio).Not.Nullable().Cascade.SaveUpdate().Column("PortfolioId");
            References(x => x.Tag).Not.Nullable().Cascade.SaveUpdate().Column("TagId");
        }
    }

 public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag> {

        public TagMap() {
            Table("Tag");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.TagId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("TagId");
            Map(x => x.TagVal).Column("Tag").Not.Nullable();
            //HasMany(x => x.PortfolioTag).KeyColumn("TagId");
           // HasMany(x => x.PortfolioTag).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().Fetch.Join().KeyColumn("TagId");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Portfolio).Table("PortfolioTag").ParentKeyColumn("PortfolioId").ChildKeyColumn("TagId").LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The previous mapping was correct. I would avoid many-to-many...

Comment: which previous mapping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33188831/1679310

Comment: this did not allow me to save the tags though. On portfoliotag do i need to add the portfolio item to the portfoliotag. there seems to standard way of doing this. May move to entity framework

Comment: When you post a question exclude all properties and mappings which are not part of the problem. I was overwhelmed by the amount of code and almost skipped the question. Others might skip faster.

Answer (score 0):

given the classes

```
public class Portfolio
 {
    public Portfolio()
    {
        Tag = new List<Tag>();
    }
    public virtual int PortfolioId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tag { get; protected set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the this mapping should suffice

```
public class PortfolioMap : ClassMap<Portfolio>
{
    public PortfolioMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PortfolioId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("PortfolioId");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tag)
            .Table("PortfolioTag")
            .ParentKeyColumn("PortfolioId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("TagId")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

assigning existing tags has to be handled in code which can cache or query involved tags more efficiently than automatic querying by any framework.

**Update:**

example usage which works for me

```
public void Save(int portfolioId, IEnumerable<string> tagnames)
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var tags = Session.QueryOver<Tag>().WhereProperty(x => x.Name).In(tagnames).List();

        var portfolio = session.Get<Portfolio>(portfolioId);
        portfolio.Tags.Clear();
        portfolio.Tags.AddRange(tags);
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i added this amend. The one thing that is still happening is the middle joining table is not adding records on insert. It works on updates. Also on updates the right table, i.e. the tags are duplicated again rather than refering to the existing record